# Why didn't European VW cars owners get any reimburse after VW scandal?

Tags: european-union, fraud, vehicle

[I read that Volkswagen broke some American laws](http://The%20VW%20emission%20scandal,%20what%20laws%20or%20regulations%20were%20broken?) on the answer to another question, but it still baffles me how come in Europe there was no class action against the company.

Besides, VW admitted to have lied, and since people bought a car with precise characteristics (that were not real), I wonder if that would be a fraud.

Comment: What EU law do you think they violated?

Comment: Fraud? I mean... If you said "buy this because its emissions are X" and then I find them to be Y, and you said "yep, I lied", wouldn't that be a fraud?

Comment: Limit your question to a European jurisdiction.  EU Consumer Protection laws for defects provide for a minimum standard. Criminal law is matter of each country.

Comment: It was in fact limited to EU. Well I reside in Germany, but I don't think here that the fact itself is open to interpretation

Comment: The manipulation, but not necessarily that this amounts to fraud under German Criminal Code. And even if it was fraud, the victims may not have been the consumer buyers, but the resellers  VW sold the vehicles to.

Comment: Well, that would make some sense up to the point that the car ultimately belongs to the consumer, if it is bought. Strange though, that in USA laws to prevent this exist, while in EU they don't...